# Energy of a solution of the wave equation.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Let $f\in\operatorname{C}^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in\operatorname{C}^1(\mathbb{R})$ be function whose support are compact. By considering a solution $u$ of the problem
$$ \begin{cases} u_{tt}(x,t) - u_{xx}(x,t) = 0,\text{ for  } (x,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2\\ u(\cdot, 0) = f\\ u_{t}(\cdot,0) = g
\end{cases}$$
How to show that $F(x,t) = |\nabla u(x,t)|^2$ has compact support and the energy function
$$E(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}F(x,t)dx$$
can be written as
$$E(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)^2 + f'(x)^2 dx$$

By drawing the dependence domains, I can "show" the first part, but I'm having trouble in writing it down formally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write down something formally, you need some symbols as ingredients from which  formulas will be cooked. Let's say the supports of $f$ and $g$ are contained in interval $[a,b]$. Using D'Alembert's formula you will see that $u(x,t)=0$ when $x>b+t$ or $x<a-t$. Hence, for each fixed $t$ the function $|\nabla u(x,t)|$ is compactly supported in $x$.

The part about $E$ actually asks you to show that $E$ is independent of $t$: this is why $E(t)=E(0)=\int g^2+(f')^2$. So, take the derivative $E'(t)$ and massage it into zero: 
$$
E'(t) =  \int (u_tu_{tt}+u_xu_{xt}) =
\int (  u_tu_{xx}+u_xu_{xt})
 = \int  (u_tu_x)_x      =0
$$